# How do I set additional IP addresses on an existing interface in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I need to setup on my VPS a failover IP address for my main ethernet interface.

I can find any kind of guide/tutorial for Debian 7 and 8 but they just won't work for Debian 9 (Stretch) since something about network interfaces changed in this version.

[OVH's *Configure a failover IP with Debian* instructions](https://www.ovh.com/world/g2042.configure_a_failover_ip_with_debian) is one such guide, which I have been following.
I edited `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens4
iface ens4 inet dhcp

auto ens4:0
iface ens4:0 inet static
address -IP i won't type on pastebin-
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast -same IP as before-
```

Restarting the `networking` service yielded these messages in the log:

```
gen 25 11:37:26 vps370990 ifup[15870]: DHCPACK of MY_VPS_IP from DHCP_SERVER_IP.
gen 25 11:37:26 vps370990 ifup[15870]: bound to MY_VPS_IP -- renewal in 34720 seconds.
gen 25 11:37:26 vps370990 ifup[15870]: Cannot find device "ens4:0"
gen 25 11:37:26 vps370990 ifup[15870]: ifup: failed to bring up ens4:0
gen 25 11:37:27 vps370990 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
gen 25 11:37:27 vps370990 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
gen 25 11:37:27 vps370990 systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
gen 25 11:37:27 vps370990 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please detail what you have done and what you need exactly.

Comment: Are you looking for bounding setup ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm trying to achieve exactly this : https://www.ovh.com/world/g2042.configure_a_failover_ip_with_debian but on Debian Stretch. What I did is simply following the istructions - and I suppose correctly, since the guys from that website confirmed me that "this contain an error if applied on Debian 9 but works on Debian 8"

Comment: @francoisP I'm sorry but I don't know if that's what I need. Basically the company which provides me this VPS activated an additional IP as I requested. Now I simply want to configure the network interface I already use to make use of both the old and the new IPs, to subsequently set through a cpanel-like panel the new IP as dedicated IP to a website, and leave all the other websites listening on the old IP. The guide I tried following is on my above comment

Comment: Please detail what you did in your own question *exactly* and not sending some random link here.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I edited the /etc/network/interfaces file to this : https://pastebin.com/6YMGvfpw

then I tried restarting the "networking" service and I got this errors :
https://pastebin.com/7Djg7CUj

Comment: Is that netmask ok?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's the same netmask I use on my working network interface and the one the provider told me to set, so it should be correct

Comment: I would swear the interfaces config seems ok.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ok, for some reason I cannot understand yet the logical network device name is not "ens4" but "ens3", even if it's called ens4 in the interfaces settings file. Indeed I see ens3 using both "ifconfig" and "lshw -C network | grep 'logical name'". I edited my interfaces file leaving the ens4 part as it is with dhcp and assigning my new IP to ens3:0 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

On debian 9 I added a failover IP like this:

backup old conf

```
cp /etc/systemd/network/50-default.network /etc/systemd/network/50-default.network.bak
```

edit the network file

```
vim /etc/systemd/network/50-default.network
```

add the new [Address] block (1 per IP Address)

```
[Address]
Address=139.130.4.5/32
[Address]
Address=138.131.5.6/32
```

Now restart

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> @RuiFRibeiro ok, for some reason I cannot understand yet the logical network device name is not "ens4" but "ens3", even if it's called ens4 in the interfaces settings file. Indeed I see ens3 using both "ifconfig" and "lshw -C network | grep 'logical name'". I edited my interfaces file leaving the ens4 part as it is with dhcp and assigning my new IP to ens3:0 and it works. -- qwert

Actually, the `ens4` lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` are probably completely non-functional, and the main `ens3` interface is getting configured by NetworkManager using its default setting - which is to use DHCP.

`ens4` would explicitly refer to NIC in PCIe hotplug slot #4 and `ens3` likewise to PCIe hotplug slot #3. So if there is no NIC in slot #4, that's why the

```
allow-hotplug ens4
iface ens4 inet dhcp
```

lines are getting ignored.